# DVLUP alike sites - Windows Phone apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 applications. I would like to send my apps for some competition with prizes to win. So far I found that best site for this is DVLUP. But I'm sure that many other contests are organized like Geek Club etc. DVLUP is really nice but I'm fed up with missing cool contests and centralized place to find out about them would be cool (like DVLUP but more than just one organizer)

Comment: Attempting to get more referral accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DVLUP Is hands down the most supported, best prizes, and most quickly updated site there is for Windows Phone Development Challenges. It is hosted by Nokia and partners with all of the big names like Microsoft and Telerik to bring a well rounded experience to all Windows Phone Developers. I pushed an app out a few months ago that got me 5400 points! For just 1 app! (That is almost the equivalent to $300)

To ANYONE experienced or not, I 100% stand behind DVLUP. It is a great way to focus the collective of developers in on the vacumes in the market, while also paying out HUGE dividends to those that take part in the programs. Not to mention they do a bunch of great events around the world. Just like the one I took part in last weekend in Boston. It was called DVLUP Day. A TON of fun.

Okay I am off my soap box. DVLUP is the best site there is. You can look at others but it's the best.